# brother printer lan connection to my computer

Tags: debian, printer, lan, debian-wheezy

I have a Brother HL-5250DN that was working through a lan connected to a Windows xp system.
I removed Windows and installed R4W which is a Debian wheezy Linux. I can not get the printer to work.

Comment: does that Printer support that Linux OS? that's your first step.

Comment: "I can not get the printer to work." What happens? Any error messages? One guess: you're using a PCL driver and the printer is set to PostScript; that will print nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a driver and Wheezy tends to lag on a lot software.  Verify that you have the latest version of CUPS available from the Wheezy repository (using Apper).  If it doesn't contain support for the HL-5250DN, you can download the driver from Brother [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5250dn_all&os=128).